# Going to need to frequently update a graph in a web application, what technology should I use?

Tags: python, web-applications, graph

I've got some code in Python that I'd like to start trying to turn into a web app (not sure what framework I'll use yet, but it will be python-based). The idea is that the user punches in a bunch of numbers, and a graph is updated after each is entered.

Currently I'm doing this with python + matplotlib. My initial thought was to re-render a jpg of the image each time the user punches in a new number, but this seems a little heavy.

I'm wondering, what is a technology I should look at for incorporating a dynamic graph into my web application?

Comment: take a look at [d3.js](http://d3js.org/) (and if you search a little you should be able to find examples that combine it with python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

regenerating a jpeg for every number would be very heavy.

Javascript provides a number of extremely high quality free graphing libraries:
http://webdesignledger.com/resources/13-useful-javascript-solutions-for-charts-and-graphs

In addition to the above link there are tons of stack overflow posts on javascript graphing libraries.

If you need to process each user input with python then i would consider using ajax. It could be like:

1. user inputs a number
2. browser/javascript makes an ajax request to your python app
3. python processes and returns the appropriate data
4. browser recieves response and updates the JS chart